# How to initiate Tor Browser using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, tor, firefox-profile

I m trying to open the webpage in Tor Browser using Python

Code:

```
# Start :Code For TOR Browser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

# path to TOR binary
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe')
# binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vidalia Bridge Bundle\\Tor\\tor.exe')
#path to TOR profile
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default')

# cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
# cap["marionette"] = False
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary= binary, executable_path="C:\\Python\\scrapy-master\\Projects\\kgooglecom\\WithScreenshot\\geckodriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, firefox_binary= binary, executable_path="C:\\Python\\scrapy-master\\Projects\\kgooglecom\\WithScreenshot\\geckodriver.exe")
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary= binary, executable_path=r"C:\\Python\\scrapy-master\\Projects\\kgooglecom\\WithScreenshot\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot1.png")
driver.quit()

# End :Code For TOR Browser
```

I Use [this link](http://%20https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.17.0) to download the geckodriver

Error:

[image]

Please suggest me how to resolve this error

Answer (score 4):

To open a webpage through *Tor Browser* using *Python* you can use the *Firefox Profile* and the **tor daemon** and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
  import os

  torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\AtechM_03\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
  profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\AtechM_03\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
  profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
  profile.update_preferences()
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://check.torproject.org")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Tor_Browser]

Comment: do you know how to avoid opening Tor, but to let it run in the background?